# C# call a button class into another class

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, button, eventtrigger

I'm OO programming in C# and bumped into a problem.
I got this piece of code here (this is the button `btn_delete_click`)

```
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                if (objBestand.bestandsnaamString == file2)
                {
                    objBestand.VerwijderBestand();

                     // btn_ophalen_click?
                }
            }
```

Now I want to call the "function" of another button at "`btn_ophalen_click?`"

This is the button I want to call there

```
    private void btn_Ophalen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string PathString;  //  maak string aan 
            PathString = textBox1.Text + @":\" + textBox2.Text; //vul_list string mwet waarde
            objBestanden = new clsBestanden();
            objBestanden.Zoekbestanden(PathString);  // Roep method Zoekbestanden aan 
            vul_list();  // vul lijst of form
    }
```

When I click the `btn_delete_click`, it deletes a file, and then has to "trigger" `btn_ophalen_click`
I hope I gave enough info.

Comment: Just move the code in btn_Ophalen_Click into a separate method. Then you can call this method from inside your if statement and from btn_Ophalen_Click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is bad practice to call event as method. The best way to do want you want is to move event code to separate method:

```
 //part of btn_delete_click event code
 if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
  {
      if (objBestand.bestandsnaamString == file2)
      {
          objBestand.VerwijderBestand();

          Ophalen();
      }
  }

private void btn_Ophalen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Ophalen();
}

private void Ophalen()
{
    string PathString;  //  maak string aan
    PathString = textBox1.Text + @":\" + textBox2.Text; //vul_list string mwet waarde
    objBestanden = new clsBestanden();
    objBestanden.Zoekbestanden(PathString);  // Roep method Zoekbestanden aan 
    vul_list();  // vul lijst of form
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should always keep the action inside the event in a separate method.

```
private void btn_delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Delete();
}

private void btn_Ophalen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Open();
}

private void Delete()
{
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        if (objBestand.bestandsnaamString == file2)
        {
            objBestand.VerwijderBestand();
            Open();
        }
    }
}

private void Open()
{
    string PathString;  //  maak string aan 
        PathString = textBox1.Text + @":\" + textBox2.Text; //vul_list string mwet waarde
        objBestanden = new clsBestanden();
        objBestanden.Zoekbestanden(PathString);  // Roep method Zoekbestanden aan 
        vul_list();  // vul lijst of form
}
```

Comment: Looks good to ;) but i didn't show all the code a part of the delete function is in another class, but if the code is as shown above this is perfect

Comment: Keep all the delete code inside the Delte() method, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I think `button.PerformClick();` perform click is what you [need](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkkb40tf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).
But better extract method `Ophalen()` with needed arguments and call it in both button click handlers

Answer (score 0):

you can just do something like this.

```
public void toDo()
{
 string PathString;  //  maak string aan 
        PathString = textBox1.Text + @":\" + textBox2.Text; //vul_list string mwet waarde
        objBestanden = new clsBestanden();
        objBestanden.Zoekbestanden(PathString);  // Roep method Zoekbestanden aan 
        vul_list();  // vul lijst of form
}

if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            if (objBestand.bestandsnaamString == file2)
            {
                objBestand.VerwijderBestand();
                toDo()
            }
        }
```

Comment: i can't do it like that in OO programming ;)

Comment: Technically you *could*, but its bad practice as you're duplicating code instead of reusing it

Comment: you can puth code in a method and just call the method...I edited the answers